# How easy is the new Blender to pick up?

Tags: interface, edit-mode

So, I used to use Blender a lot in the past for photography/game development purposes. I've recently decided to start using it again, however it feels so very different from when I last used it roughly a year ago...

Is it going to be easy to pick up from where I left off or am I going to have to re-learn the program from scratch?

Thanks,
Cam.

Comment: Totally fluent transition... (in my opinion)